# How to fill in missing value of the mean of the other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, missing-data

I had a movie dataset including 'budget' and 'genres' attributes.

I'd like to fill in the missing value of budget with the mean budget of each genre.

I first create two dataframes with or without budget.

```
BudgetNull = data[data['budget'].isnull()]
BudgetNotNull = data[data['budget'].notnull()]
```

Then, calculate the mean budget of each genre based on the BudgetNotNull dataset.

```
budget_of_genre = BudgetNotNull.groupby('genres')['budget'].mean()
```

[image]

Finally, I'd like to fill in the budget of BudgetNull based on its genre.

[image]

For instance, 'Marine Boy' is a action movie, therefore, fill in budget_of_genre['Action'].

How do I do this via for loop? Or there's other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a transform as follows could work:

```
df["budget"] = df.groupby("genres")["budget"].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

The mean calculation uses only the non-null values in its calculation. So the mean of each group's non-null values are imputed to that same group's null values.

See also [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966018/pandas-filling-missing-values-by-mean-in-each-group).

Comment: Thank you Wes for your help. Does this method take the instances with missing budget into account as well? Can I remove them when calculating the mean value?

Comment: It will fill only the null values using the mean of the non-null values. What do you mean by 'missing'? Deliberately missed or just null values?